# How to make a Worst case in mergesort in c?

Tags: c, mergesort

DataCount is how many times at sorting numbers.

```
  int* MakeMWData(int DataCount)
  {
```

// make array

```
int* Data = (int*)malloc(DataCount*sizeof(int));

int number = 2;
int count = 0;
Data[0] = 1;
```

// input data

```
int i,j;
for( i = DataCount;; i/=2)
{
    count++;
    for( j = 1; j<DataCount;j++)
    {
```

//merge sort worst

i think this isn't correct.

```
        if(j%i == 0 && j %(i * 2) != 0)
        {
            Data[j] = number;
            number++;
        }
    }
    if(i==1)
        break;
}
for( i = 0; i<DataCount ; i++)
{
    if(Data[i] ==0)
        Data[i] = number;
    number++;
}
return Data;
   }
```

Making worst Data in main function.

```
    int* MergeData = MakeMWData(DataCount[i]);
```

Comment: There is no worst-case; a "standard" merge-sort always performs the same number of operations.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594112/worst-input-data-on-mergesort/24594419#24594419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way mergesort works is dividing the array in two arrays, recursively (`logn` times), untill being able to compare pairs of elements. Then it merges the recursively created arrays  also sorting them at the same time.

For some sorting algorithms (e.g. quicksort), the initial order of the elements can affect the number of operations to be done. However it doesn't make any change for mergesort as it will have to do exactly the same number of operations anyway: recursively divide into small arrays and then merge them back, in total `Θ(nlogn)` time.

Comment: So, Is there a no worst case in merge sort?

Comment: @user3450300 Exactly.

Comment: @user3450300 see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594112/worst-input-data-on-mergesort/24594419#24594419