# When will the worst case of Merge Sort occur?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I know that worst case on mergesort is O(nlogn), the same as the average case.

However, if the data are ascending or descending, this results to the *minimum number of comparisons*, and therefore mergesort becomes faster than random data. So my question is: What kind of input data produces the *maximum number of comparisons* that result to mergesort to be slower?

The answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042184/how-to-make-a-worst-case-in-mergesort-in-c) question says:

> For some sorting algorithms (e.g. quicksort), the initial order of the
>   elements can affect the number of operations to be done. However it
>   doesn't make any change for mergesort as it will have to do exactly
>   the same number of operations anyway: recursively divide into small
>   arrays and then merge them back, in total Θ(nlogn) time.

However this is wrong. At the point we have two subarrays and we want to merge them if the initial data are sorted we will have only n/2 comparisons. That is all the elements of the first subarray with *only* the first element of the second array. However we can achieve more than that. I'm looking for that input data.

Comment: @user1990169 thanks a lot for your comment. That also needs the same time as with ascending data, as at this case the first element of the first array will be compared with all the elemenents of the second array. After that all the rest elements of the first array will be copied without any comparison :) So yes, descending order is also a best case at mergesort :)

Comment: The quote is correct; there is always one comparison per merged element.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you're saying.  You're saying that in the "best" case, the first half all comes from one subarray, which means that you could skip comparisons for the second half?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True :) And that makes the mergesort faster

Comment: Well, you can run a maximum of `n` comparisons per merge, so that would be the worst-case.  So that's any data where neither of the subarrays is exhausted until the merge is complete (which should be pretty easy to construct).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, that's true. But what format the initial array should have, in order for mergesort to need the maximum number of comparisons per each step? (Btw, the maximum number of comparisons are n-1 but that doesn't matter)

Comment: For the final merge stage, subarrays of 0,2,4... and 1,3,5... would cause it, right?  Now apply that decomposition to each subarray recursively.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, this cause the maximum number of comparisons at the final level. What is the input that gives us this format at the last stage, but in every previous stage as well?

Comment: As I said, apply the same decomposition to each of the subarrays, that will give you worst-case for the penultimate stage too.  Then apply recursively.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The worst case of merge sort will be the one where merge sort will have to do **maximum number of comparisons.**

So I will try building the worst case in bottom up manner:

1. Suppose the array in final step after sorting is `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}`
2. For worst case the array before this step must be `{0,2,4,6,1,3,5,7}` because here left subarray=`{0,2,4,6}` and right subarray=`{1,3,5,7}` will result in maximum comparisons.(*Storing alternate elemets in left and right subarray*)

   **Reason:** Every element of array will be compared atleast once.
3. Applying the same above logic for left and right subarray for previous steps : For array `{0,2,4,6}` the worst case will be if the previous array is `{0,4}` and `{2,6}` and for array `{1,3,5,7}` the worst case will be for `{1,5}` and `{3,7}`.
4. Now applying the same for previous step arrays:
   *For worst cases*: `{0,4}` must be `{4,0}` , `{2,6}` must be `{6,2}` ,`{1,5}` must be `{5,1}` `{3,7}` must be `{7,3}` . Well if you look clearly this step is **not necessary** because if the size of set/array is 2 then every element will be compared atleast once even if array of size 2 is sorted.

### Now going top down and analyzing the situation

```
Applying Merge Sort using Divide and Conquer

Input array arr[] = [4,0,6,2,5,1,7,3]
                           /  \
                          /    \
                  [4,0,6,2] and [5,1,7,3]
                     / \           / \
                    /   \         /   \
                 [4,0] [6,2]    [5,1] [7,3]       Every pair of 2 will be compared atleast once therefore maximum comparison here
                   |     |        |     |
                   |     |        |     |
                 [0,4] [2,6]    [1,5] [3,7]      Maximum Comparison:Every pair of set is used in comparison     
                   \     /        \     /                        
                    \   /          \   /
                 [0,2,4,6]      [1,3,5,7]        Maximum comparison again: Every pair of set compared
                      \             /
                       \           / 
                     [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

**Now you can apply the same logic for any array of size n**

Below is the program which implements the above logic.

*Note:The below program isn't valid for powers of 2 only. It is a generalized method to provide the worst case for any array of size n. You can try different arrays for input by yourself.*

```
class MergeWorstCase
{
    public static void print(int arr[])
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<left.length;i++)
                arr[i]=left[i];
        for(j=0;j<right.length;j++,i++)
                arr[i]=right[j];
    }

    //Pass a sorted array here
    public static void seperate(int[] arr) { 

            if(arr.length<=1)
                return;

            if(arr.length==2)
            {
                int swap=arr[0];
                arr[0]=arr[1];
                arr[1]=swap;
                return;
            }

        int i,j;
        int m = (arr.length + 1) / 2;
        int left[] = new int[m];
        int right[] = new int[arr.length-m];

        for(i=0,j=0;i<arr.length;i=i+2,j++) //Storing alternate elements in left subarray
            left[j]=arr[i];

        for(i=1,j=0;i<arr.length;i=i+2,j++) //Storing alternate elements in right subarray
            right[j]=arr[i];

        seperate(left);
        seperate(right);
        merge(arr, left, right);
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr1[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        seperate(arr1);
        System.out.print("For array 1:");
        print(arr1);
        int arr2[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        seperate(arr2);
        System.out.print("For array 2:");
        print(arr2);            
    }
}
```

Output:

```
For array 1:
4 0 6 2 5 1 7 3 
For array 2:
8 0 4 6 2 5 1 7 3
```

Comment: thanks! I know that this can be generalised, but is there an automated way I can do that for let's say 1 million number easily?

Comment: You can create a program and apply the logic `recursively` for any array of size n. All you have to do is store alternate elements in the subarrays `left[]` and `right[]` and call recursively for `left[]` and `right[]`

Comment: @JimBlum check the program pasted above

Comment: @JimBlum The method isn't specific for powers of 2 only. You can provide input array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} which has length=9 and you will get worst case as ={8,0,4,6,2,5,1,7,3} which is a worst case and every number will be used in comparison at every step of merging.

Comment: @JimBlum Just remember when arr[] is of odd size then left subarray will have 1 element more than right subarray. e.g `arr[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` then `left[]={0,1,2,3,4}` and `right[]={5,6,7,8}`. Then you can analyse the worst case by going top-down. If you want then I can provide the analysis of odd-sized array also. :)

Comment: Isn't the worst case where it does the maximum number of swaps? The maximum number of comparisons is fixed for merge sort for a fixed n regardless of how the array is permuted.

Answer (score 5):

### Algorithm

A neat algorithm one of my professors gave me solves this using an opposite approach. Rather than splitting the initial array into smaller and smaller blocks, you can start with a base case and follow a recursive pattern.

Base case is [1] and [2, 1], which are the examples for worst case arrays of size `1` and `2`. From that you build arrays for `3` and `4` as follows.

1. Take two arrays of sizes `n` and `m`, such that `n + m = x`, where x is the size you're looking for
2. Combine them, with the the array of smaller size put at the top
3. Double every element in the top array
4. Double every element and subtract 1 from the bottom array

Using this algorithm, here's the series of steps for arrays of size `3` and `4`.

### Examples

#### Size `3`

1. Take `[1] + [2, 1]`
2. You get `[1 | 2, 1]`
3. `[2 | 2, 1]`
4. `[2 | 3, 1] -> [2, 3, 1]`

#### Size `4`

1. Take `[2, 1] + [2, 1]`
2. You get `[2, 1 | 2, 1]`
3. `[4, 2 | 2, 1]`
4. `[4, 2 | 3, 1] -> [4, 2, 3, 1]`

#### Size `7`

1. Take `[2, 3, 1] + [4, 2, 3, 1]`
2. You get `[2, 3, 1 | 4, 2, 3, 1]`
3. `[4, 6, 2 | 4, 2, 3, 1]`
4. `[4, 6, 2 | 7, 3, 5, 1] -> [4, 6, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1]`

It's easy to see how you can take this approach and easily build up to huge array sizes.

### Program

Here's a python function that implements this algorithm.

```
import math

def worstCaseArrayOfSize(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    else:
        top = worstCaseArrayOfSize(int(math.floor(float(n) / 2)))
        bottom = worstCaseArrayOfSize(int(math.ceil(float(n) / 2)))
        return map(lambda x: x * 2, top) + map(lambda x: x * 2 - 1, bottom)
```